# How to write Angular 2+ function using Observables for a Paginated api

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I am working with the instagram api. The api provides a response as follows:

```
{
    "pagination": {
        "next_max_id": "blah",
        "next_url": "api call url here"
    },
    "data": [{ "xyz" : "data i am interested in" }]
}
```

I am using this to get observable of result: `this.http.get(url).map(...)`

I have written my own code with `subscribe` and it leads to almost an infinite loop kind of thing. I am not able to gather all the data from subsequent api calls from the pagination's "next_url".

I read about using `concatMap` and `flatMap` but need a more detailed explanation and code as to do this efficiently.

lets assume the function is as follows:

```
getApiResult(access_token) {
    resulltObservable = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
       /* 
        logic to also get results from pagination 
        and aggregate all the results 
        */
    return finalResult;
}
```

Note: At one point `pagination : {}` wont have `'next_url'` property. I want to stop there.

Comment: you want to carry on execution until there's no next_url

Comment: yes, at one point `pagination : {}` wont have any property. I want to stop there.

Answer (score 0):

I think something along this lines should work. Not sure if it's the best option though.

```
getResultsRecursive(url) {
    return this.http.get(url)
        .flatMap(res => {
            const parsedRes = res.json();
            if(parsedRes.pagination.next_url) {
                return this.getPageResults(parsedRes.pagination.next_url)
                    .startWith(res);
            }
            return Rx.Observable.of(res)
        });
}

getApiResult(access_token) {
    const firstPage = [...];
    return this.getResultsRecursive(firstPage)
        .map(res => res.json())
        // Here we will have 1 res per each page. We could combine them into a single one (optional)
        .reduce(res => {however you want to combine the results}, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this is quite a common pattern, so i digged in a bit and come up with the following solution for recursive Rxjs ajax processing

```js
// try to mock the api
let loadData = (url) =>
  Rx.Observable.of({
    "pagination": {
      "next_url": url
    },
    "data": [{
      "xyz": "data i am interested in"
    }]
  }).delay(2000)


loadData('www.xyz.com').expand((obj) => {
    url = obj.pagination.next_url
    if (url)
      return loadData(url)
    return Observable.empty()
  })
  .take(3)
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    console.warn(curr)
    return acc.concat(curr.data)
  }, [])
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

http://jsbin.com/xemowavove/edit?html,js,output